# Which metaheuristic algorithm should i use in this situation?

Tags: algorithm, genetic-algorithm, heuristics, evolutionary-algorithm

Need advice here on metaheuristic algorithms.

I have a set of numerical data (a population if you will) given to me by several people regarding the way they approach a certain problem (how much time did they take, how many resources, number of people for task, etc or failing that how hard/easy certain things within the problem was to do using a Fibonacci sequence). The results have low ends, high ends and numbers between those two so i cant really know which one is the most correct

Using metaheuristic algorithms (and which ones) how do i find which numbers are more accurate/optimal

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking. Do you want to find the average of your data? Do you want to remove outliers? What do you want to do?

Comment: @Stef removing outliers would be more apt. If for example several users tell me that it took them somwhere between 10 to 15 hours to do something (or simply that it was easy to do) i want to be able to discard the data given to me by the user that told me it took him 50 hours (and/or that it was hard)

Comment: You could take the **median** instead of the **mean**. The median is much less sensitive to outliers.